# MS Word 2013 - What style is applied to pasted images?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using Word 2013, and I paste graphs and figures from Excel as images so I don't have to mess with formatting afterwards. What Style applies to these? My issue is that there's too much space between the image and the caption above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images pasted into a Word document are by default positioned in-line with text.
This creates annoying huge text breaks around each image.

To set the default way Word handles inserted images:

- Go to menu *File > Options*
- Click on "Advanced" on the left
- Scroll down to "Cut, copy, and paste"
- Set "Insert/paste picture as:" to the new default (probably Tight)
- Click OK

This is what the options mean:

- In Line with Text : keeps the image right where you insert it, next to the text.
- Square : wraps text around the border of an image.
- Tight : wraps text tightly around the image.
- Through : similar to Tight, but will also fill any gaps in the image.
- Behind Text : to display text over the image.
- In Front of Text : to display the image over the text.
- Top and Bottom : to place the image on its own line.

For more information and examples see the article
[Microsoft Word Tips: Images and Text Wrapping](https://proofreadmyessay.co.uk/writing-tips/microsoft-word-text-wrapping/).

Comment: Great, thank you. I was thinking it had more to do with styles.